# Having a member variable only conditionally present using requires clause

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I wish to make the existence of `member` within `dat` dependent on `B` (or some other concept).

```cpp
template <bool B>
struct dat {
    void member_func() requires (B) {} //ok
    std::byte member requires (B); //err
};
```

I know this is possible to do with specialisation but as far as I am aware that would get very ugly if multiple different member requirements were nessacary.

Is this behaviour possible without specialisation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a couple approaches to this (see [Conditional Members](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2021/11/21/conditional-members/)).

One is you use the condition to change the type of `member`:

```cpp
struct E { };
[[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<B, std::byte, E> member;
```

This isn't really a conditional member variable, `member` is always present. But it's sometimes the type you care about and other times it's an empty type that takes no space. That could be good enough - if you never actually have to access the thing, and no code depends on the presence of this member.

If that doesn't work, then you do have to resort to a different sort of specialization. But you don't have to specialize all of `dat`, just a base class that conditionally provides this member:

```cpp
template <bool B>
struct maybe_member {
   std::byte member;
};

template <>
struct maybe_member<false> { };

template <bool B>
struct dat : maybe_member<B> {
    void member_func() requires (B) {} //ok
};
```

Here, `dat<true>` has a member named `member` but `dat<false>` has *no* data members. Which is important for things like `iterator_category` ([as I mention](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2021/11/21/conditional-members/#conditional-member-types)).

---

Neither are great solutions, but both definitely beat having to specialize the *entire class* just to condition on member variable. Both scale if there is a need to have multiple different, independently conditional variables.

Comment: Instead of E one could use std::monostate (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) as to improve cleanliness, that confined specialisation as an alternative is also super helpful in case there is an issue with elements in the first answer. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Vye What about `std::monostate` improves cleanliness? It's just a different empty type. You'll also want to have a different empty type for every such member, which is added reason to not use `monostate`.